# Restkit 2.0 cancellation - any hidden issues using it?

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm just started with codebase that is using RestKit 2.0 .

One of the problems in the codebase is abundance of network calls that are hard to cancel.

I see that some networking methods could easily return operation to the caller, so that caller could cancel them at will. However, interface doesn't support that easily. Have anyone tried writing their own category to expose return these operations?

For example,

```
- (void)getObjectsAtPath:(NSString *)path
              parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                 success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                 failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSParameterAssert(path);
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:path parameters:parameters];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    [self enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Could look like this:

```
- (NSOperation *)getObjectsAtPath:(NSString *)path
              parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                 success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                 failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSParameterAssert(path);
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:path parameters:parameters];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    [self enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
    return operation;
}
```

Please let me know if anyone tried this and run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the only operation involved in the process. It deals with the networking aspect but not the mapping. That doesn't mean it's not possible, but it isn't necessarily as easy as you think.

`RKObjectManager` provides an interface for cancelling in-flight operations based on the request rather than the specific operation which is more appropriate to use.

Comment: True, but it'll cancel all of the operations if they match path. It becomes a problem when you have two view controllers issuing same requests and one of them cancels it out.